# API for navigating a custom spatial graphic?

Tags: javascript, html, api, webgl, google-earth

Assuming I have location-based 3D graphics (a 3D map) with matched X/Y/Z coordinates. Is there a Web API or library that allows me to build a navigation (rotating, zooming, etc.) application on top of these graphics?

I looked into the Google Earth API, and they indeed provide me with the exact functionality I need. The only drawback is that I cannot replace their graphics with mine. Instead of having an Earth, I want to have a relatively small, but well-detailed, 3D area.

I prefer a solution that uses open Web technologies such as WebGL, and require no-plugins. But I'd love to hear any solutions you might know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. There is not a general application need for "Google Earth but not Earth" -- that's more a specific need relating to particular games.

I'd recommend Three.js as a good way to approach this problem.... you'll need to roll your own UI though